# Override GridView row style while keeping the existing content

Tags: wpf, gridview

I have a `GridView` that I want to keep its structure but add some button of my own at the end of each line.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="A" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="B" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding B}"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[image]

And for example, I want to achieve that:

[image]

I would be happy for help with how I can do this

Comment: Add another column without a header that stretches horizontally? Or why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column and add buttons there like that.

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="A" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="B" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding B}"/>
                        
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Buttons">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="Btn"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want it as a column.
I want to override the row so I can add my own content to it

Comment: @OhadCohen ahh, sorry then. I have no idea how to add without column.